# При запуске сервера nginx выдаёт 500 ошибку. Также не копируется статика для бэкенда

Tags: python, nginx, docker

### **Сами ошибки**

[image]

[image]

Честно говоря, как новичок, уже не первый день долблюсь с этим, но в голове 0 идей, а первые решения с интернета не помогают.

1. **Путь статики**

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'collected_static'
```

2. **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

volumes:
pg_data:
static:
media:

services:
db:
  image: postgres:13.10
  env_file: .env
  volumes:
    - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
backend:
  image: ishiiragiishi/kittygram_backend
  env_file: .env
  depends_on:
  - db
  volumes:
    - static:/backend_static
    - media:/media/
frontend:
  env_file: .env
  image: ishiiragiishi/kittygram_frontend
  command: cp -r /app/build/. /frontend_static/
  volumes:
    - static:/frontend_static
gateway:
  image: ishiiragiishi/kittygram_gateway
  env_file: .env
  volumes:
    - static:/staticfiles/
    - media:/media/
  ports:
    - 9000:80
```

3. **nginx.conf**

```
server {
listen 80;
index index.html;

location /api/ {
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_pass http://backend:8000/api/;
}
location /admin/ {
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_pass http://backend:8000/admin/;
}

location / {
  alias /static/;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
}
```

Comment: Как вы собирали `backend`? Приложите к вопросу Dockerfile. Также приложите результаты выполнения команд `docker exec backend ls /app` и `docker exec backend ls /`. Подозреваю, что у вас при сборке в образ не загружено ваше приложение - папка `/app` пуста или вовсе отсутствует